# Only allow user to Execute a specific procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, database-schema, sql-grant

I'm looking for a solution where a user's **only** permission it to execute **a** procedure. In my example below, that procedure is `lowlevel.ZipFile` (Main Procedure). The problem is that the procedure itself executes other procedures which causes errors.. As long as the user executes the *main procedure* and not any of the nested procedures themselves I want it to be approved.
I've looked around and found that the easiest way to deny access to execute other stored is to create a new schema. I then Created an other user that has access to the nested procedures, and created my *main procedure* `WITH EXECUTE AS` signed to the user who has access. However,when I execute the *main procedure* with that user, he all of a sudden doesn't have permission to execute the nested procedure?

The code below is for testing purposes. **Be aware** if you've a database named "SiteDatabase44", a user named "LowLevelUser_Executor" or a procedure named "___ZipFile" in the master database. A clean up-script is commented at the end.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
USE master;

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE Name = 'SiteDatabase44') 
    EXECUTE('CREATE DATABASE SiteDatabase44')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.syslogins WHERE NAME = 'LowLevelUser_Executor')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [LowLevelUser_Executor] WITH PASSWORD = N'ShouldNeverBeLoggedInAs_asdasd', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
    GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [LowLevelUser_Executor]
END
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.___ZipFile
    @Filepath varchar(500) NULL
AS 
    SELECT 22
GO
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = 'LowLevelUser_Executor')
    CREATE USER LowLevelUser_Executor FOR LOGIN LowLevelUser_Executor WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].___ZipFile TO [LowLevelUser_Executor]

USE [SiteDatabase44];

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE [name] = 'lowlevel') 
    EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA lowlevel')
GO
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = 'LowLevelUser_Executor')
    CREATE USER [LowLevelUser_Executor] FOR LOGIN [LowLevelUser_Executor] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE lowlevel.ZipFile
    @Filepath varchar(500) NULL
WITH EXECUTE AS 'LowLevelUser_Executor'
AS 
    SELECT 'Zipping file...'
    EXECUTE master.dbo.___ZipFile @Filepath
GO

GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::lowlevel TO [LowLevelUser_Executor] WITH GRANT OPTION;

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'LowLevelUser_Executor'
exec master.dbo.___ZipFile @Filepath = '' -- Works as expected
EXECUTE [lowlevel].ZipFile @Filepath = '' -- Doesn't work? Get's this error: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object '___ZipFile', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.

go
REVERT;

/*
CLEAN UP

USE MASTER;
DROP DATABASE SiteDatabase44
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.___ZipFile
GO
DROP USER [LowLevelUser_Executor]
GO
DROP LOGIN [LowLevelUser_Executor]

*/
```

Comment: If you are getting permissions errors, I *assume* that these procedures have a different owner to the one the user is executing? If so, then ownership chaining will be broken.

Comment: Yes, I created the procedure lowlevel.ZipFile and ___ZipFile with a higher permitted user. 
The low lever user should not be owner of anything. Just be allowed the execute 1 procedure.

Comment: So the actual problem, sorry didn't notice before, is that the database context changes; your procedure `lowlevel.ZipFile` is in the database `SiteDatabase44`, while your other procedure, `dbo.___ZipFile`, is in the database `master`. As a result permission chaining won't work without specific configurations (and likely not what you want here). More likely you should be signing the procedure, and then a `USER` (in `master`) created against that certificate will be able to execute the procedue.

Answer (score 2):

As I mention in the comments, the problem here is that you have a cross database reference. When working in the *same* database ownership chaining can occur, however, for cross databases this is off by default. Though it *could* be configured, there are (multiple) security implications with such a set up, so without knowing your environment I can't recommend it.

As a result an alternative would be to implement certificates. This is a simplified example, you may want/need to encrypt your certificates with a password, for example. if you do you'll need to pass the private key to the `CREATE CERTIFICATE` statement (which can obtained using [`CERTPRIVATEKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/certprivatekey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) when creating it in the second database. This is the *simplest* set of steps to get to the end goal; you will likely need more specific to your needs.

First, lets create a couple of test databases, and a test login:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE SomeDatabase;
GO
CREATE LOGIN AnotherLogin WITH PASSWORD = '123abc*()';
GO
CREATE DATABASE AnotherDatabase;
GO
```

Now I'm going to create a procedure in both databases, with one referencing the other. Then I'll create a `USER` for the test `LOGIN` and `GRANT` them permission to `EXECUTE` the procedure that references the other:

```sql
USE SomeDatabase;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.objects;
END;
GO
USE AnotherDatabase;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.AnotherProc AS
BEGIN

    EXEC SomeDatabase.dbo.SomeProc;
END;
GO
CREATE USER AnotherUser FOR LOGIN AnotherLogin;
GO
```

Great, now we have a similar set up to what you do. We can now test to see if things work (they won't):

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.AnotherProc TO Anotheruser;
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'AnotherLogin'
GO
EXEC dbo.AnotherProc --Fails, no access to the other database
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Procedure dbo.AnotherProc, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 32]
> The server principal "AnotherLogin" is not able to access the database "SomeDatabase" under the current security context.

So yeah, that was expected.

So, let's create a certificate. As this is a new test database I need to create a `MASTER KEY`, but this may well already exist in your database (if it does, you don't need to create one again, but for the purposes here I do). I also then sign the procedure that we created before. *As mentioned before, the certificate isn't encrypted, but this is something you may want/need to do*.

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'abc123!"£'; --As this is a new db, we need a master key. Obviously you'd use a better password
GO
--Create a cert
CREATE CERTIFICATE AnotherCert WITH SUBJECT = N'Allow Cross Database Queries between AnotherDB and SomeDB';
GO

ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.AnotherProc BY CERTIFICATE AnotherCert;
GO
```

Great, but now we need to alsoc create that certificate in the *other* database. Fortunately this is much easier than the days of SQL Server 2008, and we can get the binary value of the cert using `CERTENCODED`. As, however, `CREATE CERTIFICATE` needs a literal value, we'll grab the value and concatenate it to a "dynamic" batch and use `sys.sp_executesql` to execute that batch. *Like before, as this is a test, it create a `MASTER KEY` but you may well not need to do that.*

```sql
DECLARE @CertBinary varbinary(8000) = CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'AnotherCert'));

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''abc123!"£'';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + --As this is a new db, we need a master key. Obviously you'd use a better password
                             N'CREATE CERTIFICATE AnotherCert FROM BINARY = ' + CONVERT(varchar(8000),@CertBinary,1) + N';';

EXEC SomeDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @SQL; --Will create in SomeDatabase
GO
```

Great, we're *almost* there. Finally we need to create a `USER` based on that cert in the other database `SomeDatabase` and also create a `USER` for the `LOGIN` `AnotherLogin` in the database. Note, however, I don't give any permissions to the `USER`, but they do still need to be able to connect to the other database. Finally I give the certificate's `USER` permission to `EXECUTE` the procedure, (notice it is *not* `AnotherUser`).

```sql
CREATE USER AnotherCertUser FROM CERTIFICATE AnotherCert;
CREATE USER AnotherUser FROM LOGIN AnotherLogin; --They still need to exist in the DB, edven if they have no access
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.SomeProc TO AnotherCertUser;
```

Ok, we are now there and we can test again:

```sql
USE AnotherDatabase;
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'AnotherLogin'
GO
EXEC dbo.AnotherProc --Works, permissions of tbhe certificate are used
GO
EXEC SomeDatabase.dbo.SomeProc; --To demonstrate it doesn't work.
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

Success! The procedure executes the procedure that *calls* `SomeDatabase.dbo.SomeProc`, but the call directly to that procedure fails.

---

Clean-up:

```sql
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE SomeDatabase;
DROP DATABASE AnotherDatabase;
DROP LOGIN AnotherLogin;
```

---

Of course, the alternative would be to just give the `LOGIN`'s `USER` in `master` permission to execute `dbo.___ZipFile`, but it appears you explicitly *don't* want to do that.